# How can I effectively adjust the dimensions of a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, chart.js, dimensions

I am using Canvas to draw a pie chart using chart.js, and even after changing the height and width of the canvas element, it still occupies the whole page

```html
        <canvas id="myChart" height ="200" width="200"></canvas>
```

the height and width of the canvas, it still occupies the whole page

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around it. I put the Canvas tag inside a div container with a fixed height.
Here is the code:

```html
<div class="container" style="width: 300px;">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```